# Simple, non-ribbon chord diagram (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, visualization, plotly, chord-diagram, circos

I am looking to replicate a plot similar to this:
[image]
with the following criteria:

- NON-ribbon connections between points (thin lines)
- Text outside each dot
- Only 10 or so points, instead of the 30+ shown above.
- Additional colors (lines/text) not necessary.

I'm aware that there are packages like [Plotly](https://plot.ly/), but these seem to be dedicated to having ribbon-like connections, instead of thing lines. I'm also aware of [Circos](http://circos.ca/), but it seems difficult to make something that is relatively simple.

Is there a straight-forward Python 2.7 script that I can use (an online example, or online tool)?